# A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer'

Tags: react-native, npm, printing, mobile-application

Could not determine the dependencies of null.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer:classpath'.
> > Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in, is unsupported. Switch Maven repository 'BintrayJCenter(http://jcenter.bintray.com/)' to redirect to a secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol for more details.

I want to connect printer with bluetooth and then print any pdf. By using react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer, it is giving error. If any different way to do this please provide that solution.